# How to encode json dump correctly in python

Tags: python, json, dump

I have a python 3 script that should get some data from a .csv-file and write it to a json file.
During my processing the encoding is correct, so that german umlauts ü, ä or degree sign ° are like they are (# coding=cp1252 at the head).

But when I write the dict via json.dump() the encoding is gone...

**How can I write a dict to a json file with the correct encoding?**

```py
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import json
from pandas import read_csv

x={"äö": "ü°"}
print(x, json.dumps(x, indent=4))

>>>> {'äö': 'ü°'} {"\u00e4\u00f6": "\u00fc\u00b0"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because `ä`, `ö`, `ü`, and `°` aren't ASCII characters.

[`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) has an optional argument called `ensure_ascii` which escapes non-ASCII characters, and it's set to `True` by default. You can get your desired behavior by setting this to false.

```py
x={"äö": "ü°"}
print(x, json.dumps(x, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thanks man! Sometimes the little things count ;-)